# Master Slave DropDownLists in client side without postback

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

How can I have 2 dropdownlists, those are Master Slave, And when select a master item without any postback the slave dropdownlist updated?
And I am interest to use jQuery.post() ?

Comment: If the options coming from database then you gonna need AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can be useful this very like as your problem an have a complete step by step solution:

[use return value of json in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993160/use-return-value-of-json-in-jquery-ajax-script-correctly)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use callbacks, you should have all data available on the client side and update the slave dropdown using javascript. However, this approach is highly discouraged if you have tons of data. Big data will "explode" webbrowser: everything will be sluggish. Please consider UpdatePanel or AJAX query instead.

Answer (score 1):

you will have to use ajax and this could be a possible solution 
http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx