# Use Return Value of JSON in jQuery.Ajax Script Correctly

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json

I have 2 DropDownList, like Master-Slave.
This is my Default.aspx:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
            <asp:Label ID="MsLbl" runat="server" Text="Groups" />
                </td>
                <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="Masterddl" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="G1" Value="G1" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="G2" Value="G2" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="G3" Value="G3" />
            </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Svlbl" runat="server" Text="Members" />
            </td>
                <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="Slaveddl" runat="server" />
            </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my Script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('select#Masterddl').change(function () {
    MasterChangeHandler($(this).val());
});

function MasterChangeHandler(Value) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'Post',
        url: 'MasterSlaveHandler.ashx',
        dataType: "text",
        data: 'ItemSelected=' + Value,
        async: 'true',
        success: function (data) { SuccessHandler1(data); }

    });
}


function SuccessHandler1(data) {
    $('select#Slaveddl').empty();
    $.each(data, function (i, slaveValue) {
        $('select#Slaveddl').append(
    $('<option></option>').val(slaveValue.Value).html(slaveValue.Text)
    );
    });
}
```

And My Handler:

```
public class SlaveValues {
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}


public class MasterSlaveDropDownListsHandler : IHttpHandler {
    public bool IsReusable {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
        string valueSelected = context.Request["ItemSelected"];
        List<SlaveValues> slaveValues = new List<SlaveValues>();
        SlaveValues sv;

        sv = new SlaveValues();
        sv.Text = "SV1";
        sv.Value = valueSelected + "s1";
        slaveValues.Add(sv);

        sv = new SlaveValues();
        sv.Text = "SV2";
        sv.Value = valueSelected + "s2";
        slaveValues.Add(sv);


        string responseText =
    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(slaveValues);
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/json";
        context.Response.Write(responseText);
    }
}
```

but there is nothing to append. 
Also I see the response in firebug windows as following(when I Select G2 from Master ddl):

```
[{"Value":"G2s1","Text":"SV1"},{"Value":"G2s2","Text":"SV2"}]
```

And for more specific view the following pic is the JSON tab in firebug windows when I select G3 in Master ddl:

[image: JSON tab in firebug window]

I change my success method of script with this new one for test:

```
function SuccessHandler2(data) {
    $('select#Slaveddl').empty();
    $.each(data, function (i, slaveValue) {
        $('select#Slaveddl').append(
    $('<option></option>').val('Member' + i).html('Member' + i)
    );
    });
}
```

when try this new script the binding to Slave ddl work correctly but with some additional items : the index show member0 to member30 and I don' know why.

I also try this one and append correctly:

```
function SuccessHandler3(data) {
var values = [{ "Value": "G2s1", "Text": "SV1" }, { "Value": "G2s2", "Text": "SV2"}];
        $('select#Slaveddl').empty();
        $.each(values, function (i, slaveValue) {
            $('select#Slaveddl').append(
$('<option></option>').val('Member' + slaveValue.Value).html('Member' +
 slaveValue.Text)
        );
        });
    }
```

So I think there is a problem with manipulate of return value (data).

Also I try this one and just the first alert appear, apparently the (data.d) is null or unknown object:

```
function SuccessHandler4(data) {
    var selection = $('select#Slaveddl');
    $(selection).children().remove();
    alert('in handler and remove children correctly');
    if (data.d) {
        alert('data.d is not null');
        $(data.d).each(function (index, item) {

$(selection).append('<option>').val(item.Value).html(item.Text);
            alert('after append in index: ' + index);
        });
    }
}
```

**How can I use return value correctly and append to Slave ddl? Where is the problem?**

**Edit:**

Find it with some changes in script and handler as following:

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('select#Masterddl').change(function () {

    CallHandler();

});

function CallHandler() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "FinalRequest.ashx",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: { 'ItemSelected': $('select#Masterddl').val(), 'ID':
  $('select#Masterddl').attr('id') },
        dataType: "json",
        responseType: "json",
        success: function (data) { SuccessHandler(data); },
        error: OnFail
    });
    return false;
}

function SuccessHandler(data) {
    $('select#Slaveddl').empty();
    $.each(data, function (i, slaveValue) {
        $('select#Slaveddl').append(
    $('<option></option>').val(slaveValue.Value).html(slaveValue.Text)
    );
    });
}

function OnFail(result) {
    alert('Request failed');

}

});
```

Handler:

```
public class FinalMasterSlaveHandler : IHttpHandler {


    public bool IsReusable {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
        string valueSelected = context.Request["ItemSelected"];
        string IDSelected = context.Request["ID"];

        List<SlaveValues> slaveValues = new List<SlaveValues>();
        SlaveValues sv;

        sv = new SlaveValues();
        sv.Text = valueSelected + IDSelected + "T1";
        sv.Value = valueSelected + IDSelected + "V1";
        slaveValues.Add(sv);

        sv = new SlaveValues();
        sv.Text = valueSelected + IDSelected + "T2";
        sv.Value = valueSelected + IDSelected + "V2";
        slaveValues.Add(sv);

        JavaScriptSerializer javaScriptSerializer = new 
JavaScriptSerializer();
        string responseText = javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(slaveValues);

        context.Response.ContentType = "text/json";
        context.Response.Write(responseText);
    }



}
```

Comment: It is generally better to write your questions in a more succinct way that doesn't cause the reader to lose the will to live before reaching the end.

Comment: @BenRobinson Generally your right but I ask this question many times in different forums, and this is all suggestions, I write all them for ignore more repetition.

Comment: you SuccessHandler3 seems to work perfectly... http://jsfiddle.net/bVh9u/ what is wrong with this code?

Comment: @Manuel The SuccessHandler3 work correct but as you know the values not return values, just defined Manually, and I need real return value.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977105/master-slave-dropdownlist-use-jquery-ajax-ajax-and-httphandler/7977296

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the sea that is your code, I found `dataType: 'text'` which should be `dataType: 'json'`.

Please see the [`jQuery.ajax(settings)` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings).